# How to show popup in map activity (Fragment Activity) in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-popupwindow

I want to show the popup in `mapsactivity` but it shows the error. so help me to get from this

```
initiatePopupWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());
```

popup function

```
private void initiatePopupWindow(View view) {
    try {


        //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_vehicle_select,
                (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        car = layout.findViewById(R.id.car);
        bike = layout.findViewById(R.id.bike);

        ChangeFont changeFont = new ChangeFont();
        changeFont.overrideFonts(this, view, 1);

        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
        // display the popup in the center
        pw.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Popup", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It show as

> 'Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity
>   running?'

Comment: add stack trace please

Comment: 2019-02-02 11:43:06.913 6222-6222/in.datasense.gcc W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: Try to use info Window on click marker or anywhere you want to use I mostly use it in map

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much @bugfreerammohan

Answer (score 0):

on the Marker to uniquely identify each Marker, and find the match in your places array.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        LatLng latLon = marker.getPosition();

        //Cycle through places array
        for(Place place : places){
           if (latLon.equals(place.latlng)){
                //match found!  Do something...
           }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace All contexts with YourActivity.this

And YOU are showing PopUp TOO early make it through PostDelayed .. you will get it


                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                       yourPopUp();
                                    }
                                }, 1000);
```